# Best T/SQL Formatting Add-In for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Does anyone know of a real good SSMS Add-In that beautifies T/SQL, isn't too expensive and also does things around best practices for T/SQL formatting?

I'm well aware of Red Gate's tool, but ~$300 is quite a killer amount.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm

I've seen this Add-In, but it's purely about indentation.

http://www.wangz.net/sqlpp/ssmsaddin.html

Neither solution addresses the commenting and header best practices.

Comment: I'm writing an open-source formatting tool (already available but not yet "complete", at http://poorsql.com), but what do you mean by "also does things around best practices for T/SQL formatting" exactly? (might make sense to add, but I don't know what you consider best practice - is there some online reference or other resource to review?)

Comment: I think what I mean is to simply space and break statements in a way that promotes readability and uniformness of display.  So instead of SELECT Fields FROM Table WHERE Something = 15.  SELECT [Newline Indent] Field, Field [New Line] FROM [Newline indent] Table [Nextline] Where [Newline Indent] Somehing = 15.

Comment: Oh, ok - but nothing around "commenting and header best practices"?

Comment: I apologize but having a standardize header would be quite useful.  It should include areas for change tracking as that is something that is critical to the versioning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this tool:

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.asp

It's pretty good for a free product.  Nothing beats the Red Gate tools however.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [SQL Enlight](http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/)?

Answer (score 2):

These ones have some basic features
http://www.sqlinform.com/free_online_sw.html
http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm